# Issue with ModelForm and related objects

Tags: python, django

I have come to an impasse when using a ModelForm.

I'm [extending the User model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model) that comes with Django, and I'm also using a ModelForm so the user can edit it.

Following the same example in the documentation, I would have this code.

models.py

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # In this case, department is optional, so I have set 'blank' and 'null' to True.
    department = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
```

forms.py

```
class DepartmentForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        fields = ['department',]
```

The problem comes at the view. I found that I need to pass an instance of the model to the form so the save() function works without having to customize it, but of course, user.employee has not been created yet, therefore it throws an error.

views.py

```
def DepartmentView(request):
    # Here is the issue.
    department = request.user.employee
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # I need to pass the instance here.
        form = DepartmentForm(request.POST, instance=department)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    else:
        # And also here so it autocompletes the form.
        form = DepartmentForm(instance=department)
    return render(request, 'employee.html', {'form': form})
```

It works if I manually add a value to user.employee.department through the shell and then reload the page, otherwise the error is as follow.

```
RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at [something]
User has no employee.
```

Or something like that... I'm sorry, I didn't try the code above so the error could be a little different, but the concept is exactly the same.

I'm also sorry if this has been asked before. I did a Google search and couldn't find an answer to this issue.

Comment: Note that it's not usually necessary to have `null=True` for a `CharField`. If you have simply `blank=True`, then the field is optional, and will save the empty string `''` when the value isn't given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`get_or_create`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create) to fetch the employee from the db, or create it if it doesn't exist.

```
department, created = Employee.objects.get_or_create(user=request_or_user, department='')
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = DepartmentForm(request.POST, instance=department)
    ...
```

Another option is to use a signal, so that the related model is created when the user is created. Then you can assume that the employee already exists, and you can use `request.user.employee` instead of `get_or_create`.

Comment: Thanks, `get_or_create` seems to be my best bet. The reason why I included `null=True` in the model is because without it I get a lot of `IntegrityError` errors when the field is empty, even when using `get_or_create`.

Comment: I'm surprised you are getting integrity errors, unless you have set `unique=True` for the field. You could try setting `department=''` when creating the instance.

Comment: I wouldn't worry much about it, it works just fine when using `null=True` and `get_or_create`.